# Add label or header inside select list menu - ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I was wondering if it is possible to add one of these (ion-label, ion-list-header) below as a header for select menu. I want these for list of Countries and Cities

for example:

```
Country A (Header)
City A (ion-options)
City B (ion-options)
City C (ion-options)
City D (ion-options)
Country B (Header)
City A (ion-options)
City B (ion-options)
Country C (Header)
City A (ion-options)
City B (ion-options)
City C (ion-options)
```

user can only select any given city and not any countries.

how can I incorporate one of these?

```
<ion-label>Some Title</ion-label> or
<ion-list-header>Action</ion-list-header> or
<ion-option value="">Some Title</ion-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only option that works is

```
<ion-option value="" disabled="true">Some Title</ion-option>
```

as a header for your options.
Don't forget **disabled="true"**